# Run multiple instances of Access 2003

Tags: microsoft-access

How can I run multiple instances of Microsoft Access 2003 on the same machine, at the same time?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Some products in some versions of Office default by opening new files in the same instances (Excel was the worst offender for years).

I will assume that is your issue since you gave limited details.  The only work around is to open Access (Excel) from the start menu (or shortcut) then open the file from the File>Open command in the menu bar.